# Swift - Assign X Array of Data to its Section

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift4

I have 2 arrays of data that I need to display "filtered" by its "segment" (Pyme/Empresa).

Array Structure
`ArrayType(Pyme/Empresa) = [["Name","Rut","Segment"]]`

Pyme Array:

```
[["CAROLINA LORETO", "193843932", "Pyme"], ["CAROLINA LORETO", "3946758", "Pyme"]]
```

Empresa Array:

```
[["Banco ITAU", "8474938", "Empresa"]]
```

The closest that I've gotten its to display all data using the following Arrays, but it doesn't filter data. (2 "Pymes" and 1 "Empresa" I need to display in this case)

NameArray: `["Carolina Loreto", "Carolina Loreto", "Banco Itau"]`

RutArray: `["193843932", "3946758", "8474938"]`

SegmentArray: `["Pyme", "Pyme", "Empresa"]`

SectionArray: `["Portal Pymes", "Portal Empresas"]`

[image: iPhone image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a struct `Person` with `name`, `rut`, `segment`, `section` values. Then create person instances with appropriate values and store in an array `allPersons`

When you want to filter the values by `segment`, Use filter function in the array and use the filtered array in `tableview` data source methods

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    struct Person {
        enum Segment: String {
            case pyme = "Pyme"
            case empresa = "Empresa"
        }
        enum Section: String {
            case portalPymes = "Portal Pymes"
            case portalEmpresas = "Portal Empresas"
        }
        var name: String
        var rut: String
        var segment: Segment
        var section: Section
    }
    var allPersons = [Person]()
    var filteredPersons = [Person]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        allPersons = [Person(name: "CAROLINA LORETO", rut: "193843932", segment: .pyme, section: .portalPymes),
                    Person(name: "CAROLINA LORETO", rut: "3946758", segment: .pyme, section: .portalPymes),
                    Person(name: "Banco Itau", rut: "8474938", segment: .empresa, section: .portalEmpresas)]
        //without segment filter
        filteredPersons = allPersons
        //filter pyme segment
        //filteredPersons = allPersons.filter { $0.segment == .pyme }
        //filter empresa segment
        //filteredPersons = allPersons.filter { $0.segment == .empresa }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalPymes) && filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalEmpresas) {
            return 2
        } else if filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalPymes) || filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalEmpresas) {
            return 1
        }
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalPymes) && filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalEmpresas) {
            if section == 0 {
                return filteredPersons.filter({ $0.section == .portalPymes }).count
            } else {
                return filteredPersons.filter({ $0.section == .portalEmpresas }).count
            }
        } else if filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalPymes) {
            return filteredPersons.filter({ $0.section == .portalPymes }).count
        } else if filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalEmpresas) {
            return filteredPersons.filter({ $0.section == .portalEmpresas }).count
        }
        return 0
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
        var person: Person?
        if filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalPymes) && filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalEmpresas) {
            if indexPath.section == 0 {
                person = filteredPersons.filter({ $0.section == .portalPymes })[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                person = filteredPersons.filter({ $0.section == .portalEmpresas })[indexPath.row]
            }
        } else if filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalPymes) {
            person = filteredPersons.filter({ $0.section == .portalPymes })[indexPath.row]
        } else if filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalEmpresas) {
            person = filteredPersons.filter({ $0.section == .portalEmpresas })[indexPath.row]
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = person?.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(person!.rut) - \(person!.segment.rawValue)"
        print(person)
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalPymes) && filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalEmpresas) {
            return section == 0 ? Person.Section.portalPymes.rawValue : Person.Section.portalEmpresas.rawValue
        } else if filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalPymes) {
            return Person.Section.portalPymes.rawValue
        } else if filteredPersons.map({ $0.section }).contains(.portalEmpresas) {
            return Person.Section.portalEmpresas.rawValue
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```